# Find a radius of convergence of power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

I have to Find a radius of convergence of this power series

[image]

I' ve decided to use D'alambert indication:

[image]

Looking for a limit i meet a problem with a factorial

[image]

Please. help me finish this example and find a radius of convergence. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the definition of the factorial function?

Comment: what's $\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}$?

Comment: Hint: $(n+1)! = (n+1)\cdot n!$

Comment: Do you remember that $(m+1)!=(m+1)m!$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the cauchy hadamard criterion;  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem

$$\lim _{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n] {\frac{n^n}{4^n n!}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{4 \sqrt[n]{n!}}$$

Since $$n! \sim \big (\frac{n}{e} \big )^{\ n} \sqrt{2\pi n}$$
we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n!} = \frac{n}{e}$$ and substituting in the limit above you find your radius to be

$$\rho = \frac{4}{e}$$

Comment: done it. I've got the same result

Comment: I really don't think the root test is appropriate here.

Comment: @Jared this is a power series, so you don't need the usual test to determine if a sum converges. Using this criterion, since the supremum limit always exists, you will always find an answer as where the power series converge

Comment: @Ant Well, if you just use the root test or ratio test, you get $|\zeta x| < 1 \rightarrow |x| < \frac{1}{|\zeta|}$ in both cases, whether $\zeta = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ or $\zeta = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n}$.  I just think when you see factorials that the ratio test is generally more appropriate.

Comment: Ah in that sense.. Well yeah maybe it's more natural to do that than to use stirling approximation of $n!$ but I just like the cauchy hadamrd method better because it always works :-)

Answer (score 1):

Be careful. $|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|= \frac{x^nn^n4^{n+1}(n+1)!}{x^{n+1}(n+1)^{n+1}4^n n!}=\frac{4n^n}{x(n+1)^n} \to \frac{4}{ex}$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have the right test, it should be:

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n}\right| < 1
$$

Think about it: the terms should be getting smaller and smaller (to converge) to the next term should be smaller than the previous not the other way around (unless you were looking for the ratio to be $>1$).  Using properties of factorials and exponentials (namely $(n + 1)! = (n + 1)n!$ and $a^{n + 1} = aa^n$):

$$
\left|\frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n}\right| = \frac{(n + 1)^{n + 1}}{4n^n(n + 1)}x 
$$

We need to find:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(n + 1)^{n + 1}}{4n^n(n + 1)} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(n + 1)^{n}}{4n^n} = \frac{1}{4}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{n + 1}{n}\right)^n
$$

You may recognize this as the constant $e$ but if not, we can use L'Hospital's rule but first we need to do some simplification:

$$
\left(\frac{n + 1}{n}\right)^n = e^{n\ln\left(\frac{n + 1}{n}\right)}
$$

Now take the limit of the exponent:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln(n + 1) - \ln(n)}{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{n + 1} - \frac{1}{n}}{-\frac{1}{n^2}} \\
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n - (n + 1)}{-\frac{1}{n^2}n(n + 1)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n}{n + 1} = 1
$$

Therefore:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(n + 1)^{n + 1}}{4n^n(n + 1)}x  = \frac{x}{4} e
$$

Therefore the series converges when $|x| < \frac{4}{e}$.